# Is there any way to maximize PHP_INT_MAX?

Tags: php, project

I can't find this row in php.ini, so is there any way to increase `PHP_INT_MAX`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can increase PHP_INT_MAX.  As others have said, PHP_INT_MAX is platform dependent.  That means on 32 bit hardware or a 32 bit OS or a 32 bit compile of PHP, PHP stores the bit in 4 bytes (max of about 2 billion).  However, if all 3 are 64 bit, the max goes to 8 bytes (about 9e18 or 9,000,000,000,000,000,000).

So if you really want large ints, get a 64bit machine, and a 64bit OS, and a 64bit compile of PHP...

Comment: The exact numbers are 2147483647 (32-bit) and 9223372036854775807 (64-bit). http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 12):

You can not control it actually. However, if you are dealing with **BIG numbers**, I would suggest you the:

**[BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)** extension.

Answer (score 6):

Nope. It's hardware/os limitation, not PHP.
You can use `bcmath` fructions for large numbers

Answer (score 3):

No.

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php:

> These constants are *defined by the PHP core*. This includes PHP, the Zend engine, and SAPI modules.