# Why is PHP_INT_MAX so small?

Tags: php, integer

Converted to GB, it's like 2 GB.

But I'm running on 32 bit Windows right now, and I can have files larger than that just fine.

So why did PHP limit this number to 2147483647 ? If Windows can work with larger numbers, shouldn't PHP be able to do it too?

Comment: It's limited by the 32 bits installation. See more here: [Is there any way to maximize PHP\_INT\_MAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873731/is-there-any-way-to-maximize-php-int-max)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2,147,483,647 is the largest number than can be stored in 32 bits. Your processor only has 32 slots to fill with bits, a number any bigger than this will be more complex and require more overhead to calculate.
Conversely the smallest number you can have is -2,147,483,648 and this again because no smaller number can be stored in 32 bits.

If one wanted to do calculations on bigger numbers on 32 bit systems, this limitation has to be worked around. There are certainly work arounds, but on a general webapp it is unlikely to be needed.

Answer (score 9):

2147483647 is the highest signed number you can store with 32 bits. PHP stores its numbers this way because that's how they're stored in your computer. Any higher, and the math and everything gets a lot more complicated. Windows will use 32 bit numbers as well. I'm not sure how it works with files larger than 2 GB, but I guess in those cases it works around it somehow, with more complex code.

Answer (score 4):

2,147,483,647 is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 the maximum for a signed 4 byte value. You may like to use long which is 2<sup>63</sup>-1 = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: No, it's only half as much: 2^31-1. 2^32-1 is the maximum *unsigned* value.