# PHP number_format returning incorrect number

Tags: php, number-formatting

Currently I have a number that is 19 digits long, when I try to print it out it gives me the scientific notation, which is exactly what I don't need since this is a specific ID rather than a number.

I've counteracted this by using number_format() however with large digits because of processing the number and the amount of processing I'm doing load time has gone up as well as the last 4 digits being incorrect.  My environment is limited so loading in other modules may not be possible, what would be my best option?

And just for an example:

```
$cid = 8162315223029015401;
$cid1 = sprintf($cid);
$cid2 = number_format($cid, 0, '.', '');
echo gettype($cid);
echo $cid1;
echo $cid2;

>> double
>> 8.162315223029E+18
>> 8162315223029015552
```

Thanks in advance!

Thanks guys, issue is max length on x32 systems. [Is there any way to maximize PHP_INT_MAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873731/is-there-any-way-to-maximize-php-int-max)

Comment: What's your expected format?

Comment: Expected output from echo should be "8162315223029015401", I am displaying this data on the page.

Comment: number_format() expects its first argument to be a floating point value, which means you're mangling your int.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit PHP?

Comment: more over better to use sprintf which takes care of floating point issues like showing exponential value !!

Comment: @MarkBaker PHP 5.5.9 on 32bit

Comment: @0n35: then your PHP can NOT use that number as an integer, because it's WAY outside the representable range in 32bit php. 2^31 - 1 is the max for you. But even if you WERE on a 64bit php, you couldn't use number_format(), because it'll get typecast to a float to conform to number_format()'s input requirements, and STILL get the last few digits mangled

Comment: See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) for more information on `Integer overflow`.

Comment: You used sprintf incorrectly.  Try `$cid1 = sprintf("%s", $cid);`

Comment: If it's a string of digits, and not a number, don't treat it as a number, but ensure it is kept as a string. Large numbers are hard to deal with - larger strings are no harder than any other strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string;
`$cid = "8162315223029015401";`

Comment: won't matter. number_format() expects a float. passing in an int or int-as-string will just "float-ize" the number and mangle the less significant digits

Comment: The data comes from an object and using settype($cid, "string") still yields a scientific notation, any ideas?

Comment: But it only needs to print it out, so we can leave out `number_format`? Otherwise I'm not understanding the question correctly.

Comment: There's a problem with PHP handling these big integers, to make it more complicated it depends if you are on 32 or 64 bit OS. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7151387/488074) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use sprintf:

```
$cid = 8162315223029015401;
$cid1 = sprintf("%.8f", $cid);
$cid2 = number_format($cid, 0, '.', '');
echo gettype($cid) . PHP_EOL;
echo $cid1 . PHP_EOL;
echo $cid2 . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
integer
8162315223029015552.00000000
8162315223029015552
```