# PHP String to Int for MySQL Unique ID

Tags: php

I would like to convert a 17 digit unique ID retrieved as a string from my MYSQL database to a number. I use the int to do so. However I get a zero at the end:

```
$num = 96435171263250434;
(int)$num --> 96435171263250430
```

I've checked I am running a 64 bit system. I get the following:

```
php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'
9223372036854775807
```

How do I fix this issue???

Comment: What I'm going to say here shouldn't be any different I think, but have you tried using the `intval()` function? It returns the integer value of a string.

Answer (score 1):

You [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873731/is-there-any-way-to-maximize-php-int-max) exceed PHP_INT_MAX

```
$num = "96435171263250434";

$x = (float) $num; // This should hold it but it's a float

$maxIntMult = 0;

$maxIntMult = intval($x / PHP_INT_MAX); 

$remainder = $x - $maxIntMult * PHP_INT_MAX;


echo PHP_INT_MAX . " x "  .$maxIntMult. " + " . $remainder; // function of two integer if you can't work with floats and you can make something of this
```

You can try to make use of the fact that ids don't have negative values, effectively doubling your range.

```
$num = PHP_INT_MAX + 50;

$x = (float) $num;

$intX = $num - PHP_INT_MAX;

echo $intX; // Shows 50 with the '0' being -PHP_INT_MAX



function getIdWithNonZeroOffset($stringId)
{
   $x = (float) $stringId;

  $intX = $x - PHP_INT_MAX;

   return $intX; 
}

function getStringFromNonZeroOfssetId($id)
{
   return (string) ($id + PHP_INT_MAX);
}

echo getIdWithNonZeroOffset((string)(PHP_INT_MAX + 200)); // Gives 200 (store this in int column)

echo getStringFromNonZeroOfssetId(200); // Gives "2147483847" (my max int is "2147483647")
```

Comment: Thanks I am assuming there is not easy solution. As such I've decided to keep it as a string and work it like that. Appreciate the answer above tbough.