# Google Cloud Vision - PHP Error occurred during parsing

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Im using Vision API Client Library for PHP.
This is my code:

```
use Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient;
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/json.json");
$imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();
$fileName = 'textinjpeg.jpg';
$image = file_get_contents($fileName);
$response = $imageAnnotator->labelDetection($image);
$labels = $response->getLabelAnnotations();
if ($labels) {
    echo("Labels:" . PHP_EOL);
    foreach ($labels as $label) {
        echo($label->getDescription() . PHP_EOL);
    }
} else {
    echo('No label found' . PHP_EOL);
}
```

And I receive this error:

```
Error occurred during parsing: Fail to push limit. (0)
/srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/CodedInputStream.php:345
#0: Google\Protobuf\Internal\CodedInputStream-&gt;pushLimit(integer)
    /srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/CodedInputStream.php:368
#1: Google\Protobuf\Internal\CodedInputStream-&gt;incrementRecursionDepthAndPushLimit(integer, integer, integer)
....
....
....
#15: Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageAnnotatorClient-&gt;labelDetection(string)
/srv/www/site.ru/htdocs/local/php_interface/GoogleCloud.php:41
```

This is the place, where Exception goes from:

```
public function pushLimit($byte_limit)
{
    // Current position relative to the beginning of the stream.
    $current_position = $this->current();
    $old_limit = $this->current_limit;

    // security: byte_limit is possibly evil, so check for negative values
    // and overflow.
    if ($byte_limit >= 0 &&
        $byte_limit <= PHP_INT_MAX - $current_position &&
        $byte_limit <= $this->current_limit - $current_position) {
        $this->current_limit = $current_position + $byte_limit;
        $this->recomputeBufferLimits();
    } else {
        throw new GPBDecodeException("Fail to push limit.");
    }

    return $old_limit;
}
```

`$byte_limit <= $this->current_limit - $current_position` is true

Should I increase current_position? And if I should, how can i do it? Change something on server or in PHP config?

Answer (score 2):

It's a crazy thing to do!

The error "Fail to push limit" appears from time to time in forums. Various ideas are given there as to where the problem could lie. One cause could be when the source code is composed on the local PC via Composer and then **transferred to the server via (S)FTP**. The FTP programme decides on the basis of the file extension whether it saves the data on the server in ASCII or binary format.

In vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/ there are various generated files that have a .php extension but are actually BINARY! (if you open the file, you can see it immediately, e.g. : vendor/google/protobuf/src/GPBMetadata/Google/Protobuf/Any.php)
The solution to **transfer these files explicitly via binary** to the server worked in my case! If in doubt, transfer the complete module from Google/protobuf as a binary...

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is exactly my case. But what if google API with "Protobuf" is part of the plugin in my case? It is packaged in a zip archive, and on different hostings, it gives different results. Any ideas on how to fix this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: @alexander.khmelnitskiy In my case, I installed it via Composer on my Windows development and then copied it via (S)FTP (binary).
If you bring the ZIP to the server and unpack it there, the files should have the correct format - IF they were in the correct format before zipping.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that `$byte_limit <= $this->current_limit - $current_position` is true, so either `$byte_limit >= 0` or `$byte_limit <= PHP_INT_MAX - $current_position` are false.

If `$byte_limit <= PHP_INT_MAX - $current_position` is false, then increasing `$current_position`, won't turn it true. If you want to tweak the values, so the expression get evaluated as true, you would need to [increase the value of PHP_INT_MAX instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873731/is-there-any-way-to-maximize-php-int-max).

If `$byte_limit >= 0` is false, then modifying `$current_limit` won't avoid the exception.

Either way, it seems that the error is an issue with the `protobuf` php library, so I'd recommend you to report the issue [there](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues), rather than try to modify the values directly.

Answer (score 0):

mbstring.func_overload was 2
This was the reason of error
Changed to 0 and it worked